# Ubuntu 16.04 Not Responding When Installing Quartus

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, swap

I am trying to install Quartus Prime Lite Edition (Free) 16.1.0.196 on Ubuntu 16.04.

I run the **QuartusLiteSetup-16.1.0.196-linux.run** file. When the installation process starts, InstallBuilder gets stuck after a few seconds when unpacking the files. It stops responding and eventually I am forced to quit it by hand. Please have a look at the [Screenshot of the window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGCG4.png)

What might be causing this problem? How can I fix it?

```
chmod 755 ./QuartusLiteSetup-16.1.0.196-linux.run
sudo ./QuartusLiteSetup-16.1.0.196-linux.run
```

It isn't printing any messages in terminal. Just the installation window is opening and it gets stuck when unpacking files.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Do you have enough free space if I remember it needs few GiB's. Also did you started it using `sudo` or with root privileges? It does need system folders access. By the way start it in terminal and add log to the question if you if still facing the issue.

Comment: I edited the question. Yes, I have enough space available on my disk.